# How do I make the bot tell the user that its error? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I one to make a random number command, example : 
Me : {commandprefix}random 
Bot : Please put two arguments, a number and a bigger number.

Me : {commandprefix}random 1 
Bot : Please put two arguments, a number and a bigger number.

Me : {commandprefix}random 0.5 1.3 
Bot : 0.8

Me : {commandprefix}random 1 10 
Bot : 3

etc.

And like what I exampled, if there is any error (like character is not number, only 1 arguments, etc.), the bot will automatically tell us that there is an error.

Here is my code :)

```
@client.command()
async def random(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    import random
    try:
        import random
        arg = random.randrange(float(arg1), float(arg2))
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "Random Number",
        description = f"Here is your random number : {arg}",
        color = discord.Color.red())

        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author} at {current_time}")

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

It can only send random numbers that aren't decimals and can't detect error yet :(

Comment: what user? you, the programmer? or the discord user (client) that is interacting with the bot? and how do you want to tell ? using a notification?

Comment: If you are taking about error handling, its [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I already found the answer! You don't need to answer anymore.

```
@client.command()
async def random(ctx, arg1=None, arg2=None):
    import random
    if str(type(arg1)) and str(type(arg2)) == "<class 'NoneType'>":
        await ctx.send("You are missing some arguments! The command is random <Number 1> <Number 2>")
    else:
        try: 
          import random
          arg = random.randrange(float(arg1), float(arg2))

          embed = discord.Embed(title = "Random Number",
          description = f"Here is your random number : {arg}",
          color = discord.Color.red())

          now = datetime.now()
          current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

          embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author} at {current_time}")

          await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        except ValueError:
            await ctx.send("Please type a valid number")
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you are trying to do! From my perspective it looks like you're trying to make the bot stop if there is missing an argument! Here is what I came up with:

```
@client.command()
async def random(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    import random
    if(arg1 and args2):
        try:
            import random
            arg = random.randrange(float(arg1), float(arg2))
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(title = "Random Number",
            description = f"Here is your random number : {arg}",
            color = discord.Color.red())

            now = datetime.now()
            current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author} at {current_time}")

            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        ctx.send("You are missing some arguments! The command is random <Number 1> <Number 2")
```

This isn't organised and precise but this should show some kind of idea! Hope this helps!

Comment: There is no `&&` operator in python. Instead you should use `and`.

Comment: Oops sorry let me add that forgot I get mixed with js and python

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to handle error, modify as needed

```py
@random.error
async def random_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Wrong arguments")
```

[See the docs for more info](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=error#discord.ext.commands.MissingRequiredArgument)